# Adjust divider width if image is present

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a divider with float left property housing some text, then divider float right housing an image.  Total width of both dividers should be no bigger than 735 and I am reserving 200 for image. How can I adjust the width of the first divider to be 535 if image is present and 735 if image is hidden?

```
<div style="width:735px">
    <div style="float:left; width=????????>
        some text here
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <img src="../images/biteme.png" alt="" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-height:115px; max-width:200px; display:block" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you willing/able to use JQuery?

Comment: you can use jquery to check if the image is hidden or not and adjust on `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Really trying to avoid jquery just because as simple as this example is, the page is more complex than NASA and Nintendo combined (yeah, Will Smith quote, I know). Though I might have to either use jquery or backside.  Was just hoping for a simple CSS fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in pure CSS would be easy, you'd need a different approach. Only float one div and then the other will automatically take up the remaining space

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/gAUR5/

```
img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

Set the `img` css to `display: none` and see that the other div takes up all the remaining space.

Comment: That works, but due to other internal elements I have inside the divider (not just text), for some reason it fails in for me.  Nonetheless, you got me set on the right track and you've proven that this does in fact work.  +1, checked, and thank you for the insight.  Until this issue is resolved I will resort to back-end code adjustment (can't use jQuery because most of the image are a) hidden, b) loaded by a handler page which calls a BLOB, c) page itself is a control which by default hides internal elements unless called upon -images included, etc) Yeah, it's big.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this properly answers your question, but I think one solution may be to set the left div (division)'s width to "auto" instead of going for a fixed width. Also, you should consider floating both elements right so that the left div can respond to changes in the right div's size.

Otherwise, you will need to rely on javascript to affect the DOM elements (JQuery will make this easier).

Comment: auto did not work, which surprised me, but it's probably due to internal width division that I am missing. This solution does make sense. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JQuery, this will do this trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width;
    if($('#outerdiv #rightdiv img').is(":visible")) {
        width = 735;
    } else {
        width = 535;
    }
    $('#outerdiv #leftdiv').css('width', width);
});
```

If you can't use JQuery, I don't think what you want to do is possible.

Comment: I did not mention that I wish to exclude jQuery, therefore this will work. +1